# SQL Server 2008 R2 get common text between a group of text strings

Tags: sql, string, text, sql-server-2008-r2, words

I sure hope someone can help me out with this issue.  I have been searching for hours to find it but I am coming up empty.

In this example I have two columns in my table

```
GRP_ID    Desc
```

My group ID is the way I will identify that these products are of the same type, and desc is what I want to find all the common words.

So here is my table

```
GRP_ID          Desc
-------------------------------   
2               Red Hat
2               Green Hat
2               Yellow Hat
3               Boots Large Brown
3               Boots Medium Red
3               Boots Medium Brown
```

What I want as a result of the query would be the following

```
GRP_ID           Desc
-----------------------    
2                Hat
3                Boots
```

So what I want is all the words that appear in every string in the group or the common words in the group.

Comment: Would '3 Brown' and '3 Medium' also be one of your answers?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to create a mapping table for GRP_ID and products - e.g. Hat and Boots.

```
CREATE TABLE GroupProductMapping (
    GRP_ID INT NOT NULL, -- I'm assuming its an Int
    ProductDesc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

SELECT a.GRP_ID,
    b.ProductDesc Desc
FROM {Table_Name} a
INNER JOIN GroupProductMapping b ON a.GRP_ID = b.GRP_ID
```

Alternatively, if you don't have too many products. You could use CASE in your SELECT clause.
e.g.

```
SELECT 
    GRP_ID,
    CASE GRP_ID 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Hat' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Boots'
    END AS Desc
FROM {Table_Name}
```

{Table_Name} is the name of your original table.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would normalise your data and store the words in a separate table.

However for your immediate requirements, you first need to provide a UDF to split 'desc' into words.  I poached [this function](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itai/archive/2009/02/01/t-sql-split-function.aspx):

```
-- this function splits the provided strings on a delimiter
-- similar to .Net string.Split.
-- I'm sure there are alternatives (such as calling string.Split through
-- a CLR function).  
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(    
    @RowData NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimeter NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Data NVARCHAR(MAX)
) 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Iterator INT
    SET @Iterator = 1

    DECLARE @FoundIndex INT
    SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@RowData)

    WHILE (@FoundIndex>0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data)
        SELECT 
            Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@RowData, 1, @FoundIndex - 1)))

        SET @RowData = SUBSTRING(@RowData,
                @FoundIndex + DATALENGTH(@Delimeter) / 2,
                LEN(@RowData))

        SET @Iterator = @Iterator + 1
        SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter, @RowData)
    END

    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Data)
    SELECT Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@RowData))

    RETURN
END
```

Then you need to split the descriptions and do some grouping (which you would also do if the data was normalised)

```
-- get the count of each grp_id
with group_count as
(
    select grp_id, count(*) cnt from [Group]
    group by grp_id
),
-- get the count of each word in each grp_id
group_word_count as
(
    select count(*) cnt, grp_id, data from 
    (
        select * from [group] g
        cross apply dbo.Split(g.[Desc], ' ') 
    )
    t
    group by grp_id, data
)
-- return rows where number of grp_id = number of words in grp_id
select gwc.GRP_ID, gwc.Data [Desc] from group_word_count gwc 
inner join group_count gc on gwc.GRP_ID = gc.GRP_ID and gwc.cnt = gc.cnt
```

Where [Group] is your table.